# Is it correct that you are allowed 3,000 files per App Engine app (not 1,000)?

Tags: google-app-engine, quotas

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Hard_limits), you are allowed 3,000 files per app but I was reading a thread on Google Groups that someone's Java app received a warning when it tried to upload more than 1,000 files - he got around it by bundling some files inside jars. Which is correct?

Comment: Donncha: It would be nice if you upvote the selected answer as well. See those little triangles above and below the number "0" in lemonad answer? .. Click the up triangle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Updated from [Python Appengine Quotas and Limits]**

- Maximum total number of files (app files and static files): 10,000 total, 1,000 per directory
- Maximum size of an application file: 32 megabytes
- Maximum size of a static file: 32 megabytes

---

Guido van Rossum provides the answer in [Google App Engine issue 161](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=161#c86):

> All, the combined limit on static and
>   code files has indeed increased to
>   3000. There is no plan to increase it further. The following limits are also
>   still in place:
>
> - 150 MB max combined size of code files
> - 10 MB max individual size of any file
> - 1000 files max per directory (not counting files in subdirectories)
>
> In the quoted message, "blob" refers
>   to static files; "file" refers to code
>   files.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect now (no longer correct). https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Quotas_and_Limits 10,000 total
1,000 per directory

Comment: Link changed https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_Quotas_and_limits

Answer (score 6):

According to the "[Quotas and limits](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits)" section:

maximum total number of files (app files and static files)      3,000

The Java environment [states the same](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/runtime.html#Quotas_and_Limits)

Answer (score 2):

New numbers as of 2011:

10 000 files, 1000 per directory, 32MB app and static files total.

- http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Quotas%5Fand%5FLimits